# Python-Kivy: on_touch_down() defined to specific children affects on all childrens

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I want to make an android-lock like thing, so I have 2 Images of the button (the button normal, the the button pressed).

I defined a function on_touch_down on every image, so when I press it, it changes the source to the pressed button, and on_touch_up it changes it back to normal. But every time I press on any part of the screen, it changes all the buttons at once.

How can I make it change just each button when I press it, and not change everything when I press anywhere?

here is my kv file:

```
Manager:
    Principal:

<Principal>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 3
        Image:
            id: '1'
            size: 30,30
            source: 'button.png'
            on_touch_down: self.source = 'button_press.png'
            on_touch_up: self.source = 'button.png'
            allow_strech: True
        Image:
            id: '2'
            size: 30,30
            source: 'button.png'
            on_touch_down: self.source = 'button_press.png'
            on_touch_up: self.source = 'button.png'
            allow_strech: True
        Image:
            id: '3'
            size: 30,30
            source: 'button.png'
            on_touch_down: self.source = 'button_press.png'
            on_touch_up: self.source = 'button.png'
            allow_strech: True
        Image:
            id: '4'
            size: 30,30
            source: 'button.png'
            on_touch_down: self.source = 'button_press.png'
            on_touch_up: self.source = 'button.png'
            allow_strech: True
        Image:
            id: '5'
            size: 30,30
            source: 'button.png'
            on_touch_down: self.source = 'button_press.png'
            on_touch_up: self.source = 'button.png'
            allow_strech: True
        Image:
            id: '6'
            size: 30,30
            source: 'button.png'
            on_touch_down: self.source = 'button_press.png'
            on_touch_up: self.source = 'button.png'
            allow_strech: True
        Image:
            id: '7'
            size: 30,30
            source: 'button.png'
            on_touch_down: self.source = 'button_press.png'
            on_touch_up: self.source = 'button.png'
            allow_strech: True
        Image:
            id: '8'
            size: 30,30
            source: 'button.png'
            on_touch_down: self.source = 'button_press.png'
            on_touch_up: self.source = 'button.png'
            allow_strech: True
        Image:
            id: '9'
            size: 30,30
            source: 'button.png'
            on_touch_down: self.source = 'button_press.png'
            on_touch_up: self.source = 'button.png'
            allow_strech: True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of defining `on_touch_*` event handlers, define a clickable image class with help of the `ButtonBehavior`:

```
from kivy.uix.behaviors.button import ButtonBehavior

class ClickableImage(ButtonBehavior, Image):

    def on_press(self):
        pass

    def on_release(self):
        pass
```

Now, you can use it in your kv file. There are other behaviors, you can check them [here](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.html#module-kivy.uix.behaviors).